# JointsWP for a Beginner

Tags: css, wordpress, sass, wordpress-theming, zurb-foundation

I would love to start building Wordpress websites with Foundation and SASS. It seems the easiest way to go about this is with blank themes like JointsWP. I only have a clue on how to use this however. I'm familiar with CSS, HTML, PHP but very little Javascript and SASS. From what I've read, I can change certain SASS files and Javascript files with FTP to suit my needs.

Let's just say I want to change the "top-bar" to look different or I wanted a div that was 12 columns with a nice slider inside of it. I would change the top-bar styling to my liking in the _main.scss file; and I would add the slider in the wordpress editor like this.[image] Is that how this all works? Or is there another way I should be doing this? All the tutorials and guides I've searched for are just for foundation in a non-Wordpress environment. I have NOT found a single step-by-step tutorial or guide on how to use themes like JointsWP, and I'm to wasting too much time getting my tiny brain to understand how this all works.

Answer (score 3):

I'm working on building a site using Jointswp also. I believe you would probably want to do this in the template files. Add it to header.php or create a custom template that includes the slider. I'd love for someone to correct me if I'm wrong :)